# How to use a predict function with models converted to react native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to make a prediction, but the values of the output are very strange and out of the ordinary, I used the same model in another application made in android studio and in another format ('pb' 'txt)' and it was working, I converted to stay compatible with React Native and the output values do not match what I expected.

```
const loadMobileNetModel = async () => {
    const modelJson = require('./model.json');
    const modelWeights= require('./weights.bin');
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
    setModelFound(true);
    return model;
  }
 
  const getPrediction = async(tensor) => {

     const results = await mobilenetModel.predict(tensor).dataSync();
  }
```

**Output of the model:**

```
0.20394186675548553
212.1569366455078
221.74099731445312
207.11045837402344
```

Comment: How large is the prediction array?

Comment: Array [1,13,13,35,]

Comment: What is the shape when you exclude dataSync()?

Comment: Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 4675,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "4",
  "scopeId": 10969,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    13,
    13,
    35,
  ],
  "size": 5915,
  "strides": Array [
    5915,
    455,
    35,
  ],
}